# wpf datagrid how to set scrollbars properly

Tags: wpf

This is a newbie question, but I would like to know what is the proper way to set scrollbars (vertical and horizontal) on a datagrid. Do I need a layout control if so where and what do I set the height and width so it can resize with the screen. Saw many posting but want to know the standard way.

Comment: What is you requirement?

Comment: I just want to put scrollbars on a datagrid and wanted to know how to do that with the screen resizing